# Dynamically test fields translated through AutoMapper

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, automapper

I want to map from class A to class B. However, class A has a few property name mismatches with class B and has quite a few nullable types. In the case of a null, I'm supposed to provide a default value for that field (some int?s should be 0, some should be 1, etc). It seems like I've not got a daisy chain of about 15 ForMember calls stuck onto my Mapper.CreateMap(). (If there's a better way to do this, let me know).

Now I'm wondering how in the world I can test this concisely. I was thinking I could leverage NUnit's TestCaseSource functionality, so create a bunch of As, and basically create 2 tests for every single field e.g.

```
// given int? A.foo == null
Assert.True(B.fooVal == DEFAULT_FOO_VALUE)
// another test...
// given int? A.foo == 500
Assert.True(B.fooVal == 500)
```

I'm just not sure how to do this dynamically (or if it is even possible). So there's four inputs to the test case, A's field under test, A's field under test's value, B's field under test, B's field under test's value.

I could do this all by hand but I feel like there's probably some much smarter solution.

Answer (score 0):

From [Configuration Validation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation) on the AutoMapper wiki...

> Hand-rolled mapping code, though tedious, has the advantage of being
>   testable. One of the inspirations behind AutoMapper was to eliminate
>   not just the custom mapping code, but eliminate the need for manual
>   testing. Because the mapping from source to destination is
>   convention-based, you will still need to test your configuration.
>
> AutoMapper provides configuration testing in the form of the
>   AssertConfigurationIsValid method.

You should be able to use `AssertConfigurationIsValid`.

E.g. For, say a `ProductModel` and `ProductDTO` object you can:

```
[Test]
public void ProductDTO_ToModel_Mapping_IsValid()
{
    //Arrange
    Mapper.CreateMap<productModel, ProductDTO>();

    //Act

    //Assert
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

This would validate that everything between the two objects maps correctly. This way you don't have to use `TestCaseSource` as AutoMapper will check that the types map, without you having to feed values through the test cases.